# Как в переменную передать "$@" для последующего корректного цикла?

Tags: bash

Есть скрипт script.sh:

```
FILELIST="$@"
for file in $FILELIST ; do
    echo "|$file|"
done
```

Если вызвать его следующим образом:

```
$ bash script.sh name 'spaced name'
```

То вывод не соответствует моим ожиданием:

```
|name|
|spaced|
|name|
```

Есть способ сделать вывод корректным?

```
|name|
|spaced name|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

FILELIST="$*"
for file in $FILELIST ; do
    echo "|$file|"
done

IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Не знал. Удобно.
Только:

    FILELIST="$@*"

Comment: Да, разумеется. Копипаст - зло :)